# Is there any self-contradiction in this statement that "everything is beautiful"?

Tags: logic, propositions

1. 'Everything is beautiful.'
2. If you deny the proposition of 1), it is 'something is not beautiful'.
3. The proposition 'something is not beautiful', which comes from 2), is included in 'everything'.
4. In conclusion, 'something is not beautiful, but it is beautiful.'

1)From the logic of through 4) the statement 'everything is beautiful' seems self-contradictory. Could you please let me know if there is something wrong with the analysis?

Comment: No. First, statements with "everything" and "beautiful" typically come with implicit context restrictions. Those may be vague but abstract propositions would typically be excluded from intended "everything". And second, even if "everything" was intended universally, "something is not beautiful" can still be a beautiful proposition, so the move from 3 to 4 is invalid. It involves [use-mention error](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Use-Mention-Error.html), confusing what a proposition says with what it is.

Comment: But the title state a **single** statement that is not a contradition at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reach an absurd conclusion because your argument assumes both a premise and its denial. There is nothing self-contradictory in the statement everything is beautiful- it is simply a matter of opinion, and opinions can be as daft as you like. However, there is a contradiction in your argument because having stated everything is beautiful at line 1 you then assert a contradictory statement at line 2, with the consequence that lines 3 and 4 are utter nonsense.

Comment: I got it. So I've seen on the internet that 'everything is true' or 'everything is false' statements have self-contradiction, what's the difference between those sentences and the 'everything is beautiful'?

Comment: Those statements are claimed matters of fact, not matters of opinion.

Comment: "Everything is true." <--- What logical process goes through for this sentence to have a contradiction?

Comment: I suggest you ask that as a new question.